# FFMPEG + h264_qsv = green line at bottom of video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am experimenting with Intel quicksync and FFMPEG on Ubuntu 19.04 (https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK/wiki/Intel-media-stack-on-Ubuntu) .

Unfortunately, I am stuck with having a green line at the bottom of the outputs when scaling. Making sure that the height is divisible by 8 or 16 will sometimes hide the green bar when playing the video with VLC, but not always. Playing it on iPhone and Quicktime on Mac will always show the green line. 
There is very little about this issue to be found online so I am stuck.

Here is my FFMPEG version:

```
ffmpeg version N-95842-g103effe Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)
configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libmfx --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree
libavutil      56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
libavcodec     58. 62.100 / 58. 62.100
libavformat    58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavdevice    58.  9.101 / 58.  9.101
libavfilter     7. 66.100 /  7. 66.100
libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
```

Here is my input video:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '720p-test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2019-10-19T15:49:16.000000Z
  Duration: 00:12:04.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1206 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1075 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-10-19T15:49:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/19/2019.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-10-19T15:49:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/19/2019.
```

Here is my example commmand:

`/root/bin/ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i 720p-test.mp4 -c:v h264_qsv -vf 'scale_qsv=640:360' -preset veryfast -b:v 800K -movflags faststart 720-to-360.mp4`

Here is the output:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '720-to-360.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.100
  Duration: 00:12:04.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 925 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 791 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/19/2019.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/19/2019.
```

Here is how the output looks:

[image]

I am not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it happen when the height is a multiple of 32?

Comment: @Gyan same result when testing with `scale_qsv=640:352` and `scale_qsv=640:384`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `vpp_qsv` method (`-vf vpp_qsv=w=640:h=360`), does not replicate the problem that appears in `scale_qsv` at what I believe on some slight expense (the test file was 5.54 mb when done with `scale_qsv` but is now 5.56 when done with `vpp_qsv`)